# Representing Workflow Decision Tree Nodes

Tags: interface-design, critique

I have a workflow tree end users can build to:

- Define conditions for execution
- Perform action on condition met

Currently the UI looks like:
[image]

with blue being 'condition' and green being 'action' and root is orange.

Viso and other tools often represent the condition as a triangle, in order to represent the text correctly, that triangle might have to be pretty big.

I was thinking about just adding some sort of icon on the left of the words to represent but i dont feel that conveys the difference enough.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish the difference in the most effective way?

Answer (score 2):

The diamond is the standard symbol for a decision node on a flow chart. Having said that, I always find it inconvenient, like you, to fit text inside the diamond. I often use this alternative (a very long hexagon), which is not standard, but at least is pointy. Mind you, if somebody else is looking at your chart and expecting for it to be standard it might take them a bit to figure out what kind of node is this.

[image]